# Pattern for inheriting and using a member variable in derived classes without casting each time

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

I have a base class:

```
class Base{
protected:
    Storage* _storage;

    virtual void createStorage(){
        delete storage;
        _storage = new Storage();
    }

    void exampleUseOfBaseStorage(){
        _storage->baseData++; //some complex calculation
    }
}

struct Storage{
    int baseData;
}
```

Each derived class has their own kind of storage:

```
struct DerivedStorage : Storage{
    int derivedData;
}
```

In the derived class,

```
class Derived{
protected:
    virtual void createStorage() override{
        delete storage;
        _storage = new DerivedStorage();
    }
}
```

Hence _storage can be used for all the base class members and the derived class members.
The downside is, because for each derived class, I would have to cast the type of storage to DerivedStorage, or whatever type of storage the derived class uses, it is very tedious to type out the cast statement each time. Is there an elegant way around it ?

My solution is to just have one more variable of type DerivedStorage, and just use that in the derived classes member functions. Eg:

```
class Derived{
protected:
    DerivedStorage* _ds = nullptr;

    virtual void createStorage() override{
        delete storage;
        _storage = new DerivedStorage();
        _ds = _storage; // Use _ds in all member functions of Derived instead of _storage
    }

    void exampleUseOfDerivedStorage(){
         _ds->derivedData++; //some complex calculation
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant pattern to use for this use case?

Comment: Having to cast to a derived type is a pretty big code smell.  Why are you having to cast so often?

Comment: @StephenNewell Each derived class can have their own additional variables in their storage class, hence for the derived class to access their storage variables a cast is required.

Comment: Why not figure out a good interface for `Storage` and use `virtual` member functions?

Comment: @StephenNewell There are no member functions for storage. It is used only for storing class specific information.

Comment: Please post an example for a caller using `Storage` needed to cast to `DerivedStorage`.

Comment: @LouisGo In the function exampleUseOfDerivedStorage, to access the derived data I would have had to cast _storage to DerivedStorage to access derivedData (if I had not used the _ds variable which is already of type DerivedStorage)

Comment: It might depends on context, but using composition instead of inheritance for`Storage` would make things simpler and easier. See my updated answer. To @StephenNewell is that what you means about "rule of zero"?

Comment: @LouisGo I am currently using composition but it feels unwieldy when there are multiple levels of inheritance, as for each level there is then an additional storage variable. The beauty of your CRTP solution is that it makes it easy to pass the storage object to other classes like for memento. With composition I would need to include both storage objects in the memento, and write code for different kinds of mementos since with each level there is a new storage variable.

Comment: Your interface break [Liskov_substitution_principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): A `SubDerived` class might create a `Storage` (not deriving from `DerivedStorage`), and so `exampleUseOfDerivedStorage` would be incorrect.

Comment: @Jarod42 You are correct. Still trying to figure out the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question should be "do you really need storage to be derived?". Most of time composition/aggregation should be enough.

Even you need to calculate the data from both derived storage and base storage, you may still access both of them in derived class

### Example for composition

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/48aEv6K7x)

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

struct Storage{
    int baseData{};
};
struct DerivedStorage{
    int derivedData{};
};

class Base{
public:
    Storage _storage;

    void exampleUseOfBaseStorage(){
        _storage.baseData++; //some complex calculation
    }
};

class Derived: Base{
public:
    DerivedStorage _ds;

    void exampleUseOfDerivedStorage(){
        _ds.derivedData++; //some complex calculation
        std::cout << "baseData: " << _storage.baseData << std::endl;
        std::cout << "derivedData: " << _ds.derivedData << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Derived d;
    d.exampleUseOfDerivedStorage();
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Example for CRTP

Here's the example to elaborate on [user17732522](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17732522/user17732522)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71334271/4123703) about CRTP usage.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zYaYeKGT4)

I changed all member to public since the example doesn't elaborate on when to call `createStorage()`

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

struct Storage{
    int baseData{};
};
struct DerivedStorage : Storage{
    int derivedData{};
};

template<typename DS>
class Base{
public:
    Storage* _storage;

    virtual void createStorage(){
        delete _storage;
        _storage = new Storage();
    }

    DS* getStorage(){
        return static_cast<DS*>(_storage);
    }

    void exampleUseOfBaseStorage(){
        _storage->baseData++; //some complex calculation
    }
};

class Derived: Base<DerivedStorage>{
public:

    virtual void createStorage() override{
        delete _storage;
        _storage = new DerivedStorage();
    }

    void exampleUseOfDerivedStorage(){
        getStorage()->derivedData++; //some complex calculation
        std::cout << "derivedData: " << getStorage()->derivedData << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Derived d;
    d.createStorage();
    d.exampleUseOfDerivedStorage();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using composition it feels a bit unwieldy once there are multiple levels of inheritance. The CRTP solutions looks like what I am looking for! Let me try it.

Answer (score 2):

I would put the cast into a member function, rather than using a data member. The member function can have the same name in each derived class. If you really don't want to type out the function definition in each derived class, you could use CRTP to implement it.

Using a data member makes it impossible to safely use the rule-of-zero approach to the special member functions and you would have to implement all of them explicitly in each derived class.

I assume that the shown code is just abbreviated, but the base class has the same problem. If it was using `std::unique_ptr<Storage>` instead of a raw pointer it could simply follow the rule-of-zero and not bother implementing any of the special member functions, but as it is written in the question, the special member functions need to be explicitly defined to avoid causing UB when the class is copied/moved. (And also `std::unique_ptr` would make `createStorage` exception-safe, which it is currently not.)

Comment: Indeed CRTP makes the casting easier than hand written if there are tons of derived classes.

Comment: If you have a moment, can you please illustrate what you mean with an example? Some of these things are new to me so I haven’t fully wrapped my head around it yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because the method `Base::exampleUseOfBaseStorage` is protected, caller of this method is limited to the derivative classes (and Base).

So, if each derivative class has each storage as own member, they can use it as argument for `Base::exampleUseOfBaseStorage`.

```
class Base{
protected:
    //(This will be called from Drived)
    void exampleUseOfBaseStorage( Storage *storage );
};
```